# sql connectionstring debug step by step?

Tags: c++, sql-server, ado

Hello I hope this is my last post concerning sql connectionsstrings....

I have a win32console app written in VS2010Express and I try to connect my SQL server.
I think i did everything right and that the "only" problem is the connection string. Could anyone please confirm that there is no other big mistake in the code?

Concerning the connecting string, I have tried and tried....
One site suggested that you could get a valid string by creating a connect.udl file on the desktop, doublklick it and work your way through the dialog. When opening it again in a texteditor the right connection string is found.
In my case that would be:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Test;Initial Catalog=Stackhoover;Data Source=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS

Did not work either.... Is there a way to "debug" the string? To see what part is wrong eg "wrong pwd" or "server not found"?
The firewall is off right now, so that's not the problem.
_hr returns "E_Fail"
The debugger steps into msado15.tli line1271

Thank you out there for any help!
Happy coding!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
void HandleError(HRESULT)
{
MessageBox( NULL, L"ERROR", L"XX!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION |MB_RETRYCANCEL);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HRESULT hr;                                     //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT  

//creating a connection object
USEADO::_ConnectionPtr connection;
//create a recordset object
USEADO::_RecordsetPtr recordset;

 //      Initialize COM  
    if(FAILED(hr = CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        HandleError(hr); 
        return hr;
    }   

if(FAILED(hr = connection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(USEADO::Connection))))
    {
        HandleError(hr); 
        return hr;
    }

if(FAILED(hr = recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(USEADO::Recordset))))
    {
        HandleError(hr); 
        return hr;
    }

    connection->CursorLocation = USEADO::adUseServer; //http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/vb-cursors-and-locks.html
                                       //adUseClient;


    //Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
    connection->Open(L"Data Source=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Stackhoover; User Id=Test; Password = Test", L"", L"", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);
    //connection->Open(L"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Test;Initial Catalog=Stackhoover;Data Source=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS", L"Test", L"Test", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);
    //DRIVER=SQL Native Client;SERVER=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Initial Catalog=ADOTest;
    //connection->Open(L"DRIVER=SQL Native Client;SERVER=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Initial Catalog=Stackhoover;", L"", L"", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);

return 0;
}
```

My stdafx.h

```
 #pragma once
#import "C:\Program\Delade filer\System\ado\msado15.dll"    rename_namespace("USEADO"),rename("EOF","EndOfFile")
// Define ADO Namespace as global
using namespace USEADO;

#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Comment: Do you have MDAC installed? Is the SQL server service running? How soon do you get the error? Is it immediate? Have you looked at the logs on the server? Is the instance name correct (instance name=port number, that's why it's important) Also, you need to get a numerical error code. [This Thread](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=211179) may help

Comment: @gbn  I used sp_who2 (SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses) and it shure looks like I'm connected ! ;-) Time for a beer     Regards Lumpi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes, so:

```
connection->Open(L"Data Source=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Stackhoover; User Id=Test; Password = Test", L"", L"", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);
```

should be:

```
connection->Open(L"Data Source=PETERPAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Stackhoover; User Id=Test; Password = Test", L"", L"", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);
```

Comment: Hi unapersson ! I've thought I've already tried it, but it was in a different piece of test code. connection->Open(L"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Test;Initial Catalog=Stackhoover;Data Source=PETERPAN\\SQLEXPRESS", L"Test", L"Test", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);   Seems to work, do you know a quick and dirty way to test if I'm really connected? Regards Lumpi

Comment: @Lumpi No, I've never used ADO - like all real men I use naked ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `User ID` then you need `password`. I'd also ignore `Persist Security Info`. And you need a trailing `;`. See [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) and the [MS page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords)

I'd expect a connection string to look more like one of these depending on whether you are using SQL Server logins or Windows Authentication

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=Test;Password=foo;Database=Stackhoover;Server=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;
>
> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=true;Database=Stackhoover;Server=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;

Comment: I agree, but the system don't! The string works without a password, for whatever reason. Thank you for the link describing the connection string parameters. Very helpful!