# Test SQL Connection String in C++ (WIN32)

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008

I'd like to check a connection string on a SQL 2008 server. Problem is, I have to write the whole thing using C++ (WIN32). Is there any simple way to do this? I've googled it, but it's quite hard, since I don't have much experience with C++.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For pure C++ there is no simple way to do this. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795606/sql-connectionstring-debug-step-by-step

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string should be the same regardless of what language you implement with. To simply test the connection string you could do it a .NET language of your choice or whatever else you're familiar with.

Here's a [link to a 2-page tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/ado/article.php/c6729__1/Using-ADO-from-C.htm) that you can use to quickly put a C++ prototype app together that will connect to a db via ADO.

But with .NET, testing a connection can be done in just a few lines of code:

```
try
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here..."))
   {
      conn.Open();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Or you can use a ready-made app [like this one](http://www.digitalcoding.com/free-software/database/Database-Connection-String-Tester.html) to test a connection string.

Comment: Well, I have to implement it in a unmanaged dll, so there is no way to access classes such as SqlConnection.

Comment: Follow the guy's link to the ADO tutorial, then; the tutorial describes basic use of one of the Old, pre-managed-code ways of getting to a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple C++ sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711810%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
// SQLConnect_ref.cpp
// compile with: odbc32.lib
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

int main() 
{
   SQLHENV henv;
   SQLHDBC hdbc;
   SQLHSTMT hstmt;
   SQLRETURN retcode;

   SQLCHAR * OutConnStr = (SQLCHAR * )malloc(255);
   SQLSMALLINT * OutConnStrLen = (SQLSMALLINT *)malloc(255);

   // Allocate environment handle
   retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);

   // Set the ODBC version environment attribute
   if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
      retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0); 

      // Allocate connection handle
      if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
         retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc); 

         // Set login timeout to 5 seconds
         if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);

            // Connect to data source
            retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR*) "NorthWind", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

            // Allocate statement handle
            if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
               retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt); 

               // Process data
               if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                  SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
               }

               SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
            }

            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
         }
      }
      SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
   }
}
```