# Getting started in .net - to use SqlConnection class (VS C++)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

I am a total noob in .net, but as far as I am aware, one can use c++ to program in .net.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 and SQL Server Express 2012.

What I am trying to do is:

I am trying to get a connection to a SQL Server in code. As far as I see, this is easy in .net (see SO link at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931638/test-sql-connection-string-in-c-win32), for example), and one can use the SqlConnection class (see MSDN link at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.71).aspx), for example) for this.

How would I do this?

What do I need to do/install to use the SqlConnection class in VS c++?

I guess I need to install the .net SDK somehow, but how do I integrate it so that I can use it in VS? What are the steps in order to get as far as that I can use this class in VS Express (or do I need to get this VS.net IDE?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use .net libraries from C++ code, you should using C++/CLI, as far as I know. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx) some information about C++/CLI.
Maybe there is other way to use .net without C++/CLI but I am no sure that it was easy. C++ is fully unmanaged code in oppose to .net.

Another way is to use C++ specific library for SQL. For example Qt have not bad classes for this.

And finally: maybe try to use C# with .net? +)

Comment: Thanks for your help!!  I am getting as far as creating a CLR console App in Visual studio, and am using "SqlConnecton ^ myCon = gcnew SqlConnection;", as I gather from [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx) that that is the correct way of instantiating an object from .net. But it seems SqlConnection is not defined (obviously, since I haven't included in any header files or anything ;)). Do you have any idea what header I need to include, or what I need to do to use this SqlConnection class?

Comment: aah, using System::Data::SqlClient works!! Ill play around with that a bit. Thanks for your help so far!! I'll accept as answer :)